# how to get the duration from two dates in the following format

Tags: javascript

var date2 = new Date("04/14/2022 12:49:29")

var date1 = new Date("04/09/2022 06:16:49")

I want to get the following duration ("126:32:40 ")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution.

Step - 1. Get the time difference between both date

```
const date1 = new Date("04/09/2022 06:16:49");
const date2 = new Date("04/14/2022 12:49:29");

const diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();

console.log(diff); // Will display 455560000 i.e miliseconds
```

Step - 2 Convert milliseconds to seconds

```
let seconds = diff / 1000; // Will return seconds
```

Step - 3 Convert seconds to Hours

```
const hours = parseInt( seconds / 3600 ); // 3,600 seconds in 1 hour
seconds = seconds % 3600;
```

Step - 4 Convert Seconds to miniutes

```
const minutes = parseInt( seconds / 60 ); 
seconds = seconds % 60;

console.log(hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds)
```